# Google DoubleClick AdExchange API integration in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api-ruby-client, double-click-advertising

I am using [google-api-ruby-client](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client-samples/tree/master/adexchangeseller) gem to interact with Google DoubleClick AdExchange Seller API. I followed the procedure suggested by the [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/seller-rest/getting_started#auth). I set redirection URI and other necessary configurations. Please find the below code snippet, which is a service setup method to get authorization and to create a service object

```
def service_setup
  client = Google::APIClient.new(
           :application_name => 'PMP',
           :application_version => '1.0.0'
  )

  client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load(ENV['Google_ADX_CREDENTIAL_STORE_FILE'])
  file_storage = Google::APIClient::FileStorage.new('test2')
  flow = Google::APIClient::InstalledAppFlow.new(
        :client_id => client_secrets.client_id,
        :client_secret => client_secrets.client_secret,
        :scope => ENV['Google_ADX_API_SCOPE'],
        :redirect_uri => "http://fakemydomain.com:3000"
  )
  client.authorization = flow.authorize(file_storage)
end
```

When I run this method,I am successfully redirecting to google accepting page like  `(https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&client_id=XXX...)`
But once I click on Accept button, the web page is keep on loading. Strangely, when I press Ctrl+C at rails server then web page redirect to the redirection URI that what I set at oauth settings.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Probably thats because you dont own the fakemydomain.com. So what you have to do is: create a domain that is yours ( services like https://www.dnsdynamic.org/ )  and then use this new domain. You have to ensure that at your network you can access the redirect_uri

Comment: An easy way to test your `redirect_uri` is to set it to `http://localhost:8080/your_app/handle_oauth` and then just log the params that come back on the redirect request from Google. You have to set the `redirect_uri` such that the value used in the code matches the one in the settings, of course. I had to do this for the first time last week and this resource gave me everything I needed: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication